# Sum of correlated non-Gaussian random variables with same distribution as individual terms

Tags: noise, references

Let's say there is a sum $s$ of $N$ zero-mean correlated random variables $\{x_i\}$:
$$
s = x_1 + x_2 + \ldots +x_N,
$$
where the correlations $C_{ij} = \mathbb E[ x_i x_j]$ are known. Assume that each random variable is complex, i.e. $x_i \in \mathbb C$, and that the real and imaginary parts are independent ("circularly-symmetric").

In the case where $x_i$ are [circularly-symmetric complex normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Circularly-symmetric_normal_distribution), we know:

- The amplitude $|x_i|$ is Rayleigh distributed, and the phase $\arg x_i$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi)$
- We know that $s$ will be from the same distribution as $x_i$, but with a different mean and variance, i.e. $|s|$ will be Rayleigh and $\arg s$ will be uniform.

For non-Gaussian noise, the amplitude distribution $|x_i|$ is often assumed to follow a distribution with heavier tails than Rayleigh, such as [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution), or [generalized gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution).  Assume that even if the amplitude distribution is non-Rayleigh, the phase will still be uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi)$.

Is there a non-Rayleigh amplitude distribution on $|x_i|$ such that the sum $s$ defined above has the same distribution type as $x_i$? Or, are you aware of any cases where the distribution of $|s|$ is a common distribution with a closed-form density function?

The unique aspect of this reference request is that $x_i$ are not i.i.d., because they have nonzero correlations as defined above. For instance, [this reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11235-017-0346-8) discusses the sum of [generalized Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution) in the context of maximal ratio combining (MRC) diversity, but they are i.i.d.